# Magento 1.9 - Frontend prices are not calculated

Tags: magento-1.9, price

after an update to 1.9.3.7, the product prices are no longer calculated in the frontend.
We have 4 attributes in our configurable products.
Previously, the price was always calculated automatically if you changed the attributes.
This has stopped working since my last update.

I've already tried that:
I have indexed all indexes again.
As well as all caches emptied.
I have also tested this with the BaseTemplate for the product view.

Hmm. What else can I do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version did you update from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you upgraded from Magento CE 1.9.2.4

There's a lot of differences between 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.7, one of them was a new product_options.js file.

This may help you;

Edit your theme layout catalog.xml and add the following under the `<catalog_product_view>` handle:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
```

Do a full Magento cache flush after making this change to see the effect.

Comment: I have updated from 1.9.2.4

Comment: have other files changed as well?
I also have problems with the checkout.
It does not continue after the billing address.

Comment: Open Google Chrome developer console and refresh the cart, do you get any errors?